# Invalid report file path - Crystal - C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Estou tentando gerar um pdf a partir do crystal report. Quando executo o código em minha maquina funciona perfeitamente, já quando eu subo para o servidor me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
invalid report file path
```

o erro está estourando no momento que eu executo

```
report.Load(arquivoRpt);
```

Eu já fiz as seguintes verificações:

O arquivoRPT existe no servidor e o caminho está correto;

Dei permissão na pasta do servidor;

O Arquivo não está corrompido;

Comment: o caminho do arquivo está inválido. Pra saber mais do que isso, precisamos de mais informações...

Comment: Posta a estrutura de diretórios e o caminho que você está utilizando